# Is there a way to combine multiple csv files located on SharePoint automatically (without running jupyter notebook code every morning)

Tags: csv, sharepoint, automation, jupyter-notebook

I receive 10 csv files per day and store them on sharepoint in a folder a. 
With the usage of jupyter notebook I combine the files into one csv file and store it in a folder b. I use this file from folder b for further analysis.

Daily combining the files is a repetitive process so I'm wodering if there is a way to automatize it so I wouldn't need to run the code every day to overwrite the file.

I would like to have the file in a folder b automatically updated as soon as the new file appears in a folder a.

Comment: is this for SharePoint online or on-prem? For online You will need to implement some kind of console application with CSOM code to communicate to SharePoint and schedule it on some server You manage in Task Scheduler (and set it to run once a day). For on-prem You may implement an event receiver attached to the lib with event on Item Add.